# (PHPで) keyの連なりを表す文字列から多次元連想配列を作成し、(evalを使わずに) 値を代入したい

Tags: php, array

諸先輩方のお知恵を拝借したく、ここに質問いたします。

```
$keys = "['a']['b']['c']";
$value = 'can be anything';
```

という二つの値がある時に、以下の代入をしたいです。

```
$hoge['a']['b']['c'] = 'can be anything';
```

eval(),var_export()を使えば、以下の形で実現できますが、eval()をできれば使わない方法をとれたらと思っています。

```
eval( '$hoge' . $keys . '=' . var_export( $value, true ) . ';' );
```

三日間考え続けましたが上記の方法しか考え出せす。。。

御指南の程、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ちょっとした言語のインタプリタをPHPで書いている形になるので、簡単ではありませんが、エラー処理を端折ったりするとこんな感じで出来そうです。詳細な挙動は`eval`を使った時と少々異なりますが。

```
<?php
$keys = "['a']['b']['c']";
$value = 'can be anything';

//まずは全ての実際のキーを配列として取り出す(エスケープとかその辺は無視)
preg_match_all('/\\[\'([^\']+)\'\\]/', $keys, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$keyArray = $matches[1];
print_r($keyArray);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
)
*/
//$hoge が空とは限らないので、一旦ネストした連想配列を作成して…
$tmpArr = $value;
foreach( array_reverse($keyArray) as $key ) {
    $tmpArr = [$key => $tmpArr];
}
//$hoge が空だったり、配列以外の値を持っていたりすると困るので前処理
if( !is_array($hoge) ) $hoge = [];
//… $hoge にマージする
$hoge = array_merge_recursive($hoge, $tmpArr);
print_r($hoge);
/*
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [c] => can be anything
                )

        )

)
*/
```

Comment: これです!! これが自分の中で出せそうで出せなかった、書きたかったコードです！！これをさらっと答えられる人になりたいです!
本当にありがとうございます！脳内が雲ひとつないすっきり状態になりました！

Answer (score 0):

以下の処理でできますけれど、内部の処理は `eval() + var_export()` と同一です(include しているだけですので)。また、php.ini で `allow_url_include = On` を設定する必要があります。まぁ、参考までにどうぞ。

```
<?php

$keys = "['a']['b']['c']";
$value = 'can be anything';

$code = <<<EOS
<?php
\$hoge$keys = '$value';
EOS;

include 'data://text/plain,' . urlencode($code);

print($hoge['a']['b']['c'] . "\n");

?>
```

Comment: どうもありがとうございます。
初めて知る書き方でした。勉強になりました。 @metropolis